# int i=00100 error in TC++ for C programing Language

Tags: c, int, turbo-c++

I am an amature C programer. I can only use C Programing language.

I have a following code containing a loop in TC++IDE.
It is simple code for printing consecutiveNo. till given value,
it contains something like this:
i = 00100

in the above line when i enter 00100 the colour of normal integer value changes.(It changes to dark blue/Navy blue)

And when i use this in my loop. instead of repeating 100 times it repeats only "64" times.
Same happens with any value which is like 023 instead 0f 23.
Please explain what kind of IDENTIFIER/Variable is 00100 or values similar to it are.
And Also explain Why does it happen so ? (64 instead of 100).

Regards and Thank You in advanced !

Answer (score 2):

This happens because a numeric literal starting with a zero is interpreted as a number written in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Answer (score 2):

A numeric literal beginning with 0 is interpreted as octal number in `C` and as 100 in octal is 64 in decimal this explains what you observe.